# Zod: create a schema using an existing type

Tags: typescript, zod

I have an endpoint that should get a parameter `method` which should comply with the Axios type `Method`.

How can I create a schema with Zod that validates that the value is using the type `Schema`?

```
import { Method } from 'axios';

const Schema = zod.object({
  method: zod.someHowUseTheTypeFrom(Method),
});
```

The type of `Method` from the Axios package is:

```
export type Method =
  | 'get' | 'GET'
  | 'delete' | 'DELETE'
  | 'head' | 'HEAD'
  | 'options' | 'OPTIONS'
  | 'post' | 'POST'
  | 'put' | 'PUT'
  | 'patch' | 'PATCH'
  | 'purge' | 'PURGE'
  | 'link' | 'LINK'
  | 'unlink' | 'UNLINK'
```

Comment: `zod.string().regex(/^(get|delete|...)$/)` was the best I could do with the documentation on the README

Comment: @kellys thanks. I also found `zod.enum(['get','GET',...])`, but I prefer to use the type directly

Comment: @Dotan, have you found a way to do this directly with existing types or maybe another way that doesn't require using a Zod method like `z.enum(...)`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Reading your comment it sounds like you want to ensure that your schema is in sync with the `Method` type from axios. I would suggest doing the following:

```js
import { z } from 'zod';
import type { Method } from 'axios';

const methods: z.ZodType<Method> = z.enum(['get', 'GET', ...]);
```

Which will at least enforce that the schema on the right hand side of the expression will parse valid axios `Method` results. Unfortunately, anything more may be out of reach unless `axios` also exports an array containing the strings that correspond to the values in the `Method` type.

The original thing that you were looking for `z.something(<type here>)` can't work because zod is using actual runtime objects, and types like `Method` don't exist at runtime. If `axios` exported an array containing the methods, then that *would* be a runtime value and you could use that (perhaps with some type casting) to generate your `methods` schema (more on this in a moment).

The other shortcoming to this approach is that something like this will typecheck:

```js
const methods z.ZodType<Method> = z.enum(['get']);
```

The reason for that is because of how types work in TypeScript. That `enum` schema will only ever parse successfully for `'get'` but because the literal `'get'` is a subtype of the larger union type defined in `Method`, the resulting schema is also assignable.

So, the next option I'm going to pose feels slightly self-defeating in that it's going to require redeclaring all the values in `Method`, however, you can continue to use the `axios` `Method` type and you will definitely have a schema that parses all of the values in `Method` (ie, does not succumb to the issue mentioned above):

```js
import { z } from "zod";
import { Method } from "axios";

const METHOD_MAP: { [K in Method]: null } = {
  get: null,
  GET: null,
  delete: null,
  DELETE: null,
  head: null,
  HEAD: null,
  options: null,
  OPTIONS: null,
  post: null,
  POST: null,
  put: null,
  PUT: null,
  patch: null,
  PATCH: null,
  purge: null,
  PURGE: null,
  link: null,
  LINK: null,
  unlink: null,
  UNLINK: null
};

const METHODS = (Object.keys(METHOD_MAP) as unknown) as readonly [
  Method,
  ...Method[]
];
const methods: z.ZodType<Method> = z.enum(METHODS);
```

The type assertion for `METHODS` is safe here because the `METHODS_MAP` is not exported and we know exactly what keys it has. Now, the `METHOD_MAP` object will cause a type error if any `Method` value is missing though which means the resulting schema will parse all `Method` values as a guarantee enforced at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Is there a reason why you are not skipping `METHODS` and use `z.nativeEnum` instead? In your example, can't you just do `z.nativeEnum(METHOD_MAP)`, assuming you also set a string value on each entry of the `METHOD_MAP`? Would need to change its type to `{ [K in Method]: K }` as well.

Comment: @Souperman Do you know how to export just an a array of string from a package you have control over wihtout bringing it all as dependancy ?

Comment: I'm not sure of your exact situation, but you may need to split the package into two parts if you don't want to include the entire package as a dependency. Depending on where you're running your code and how the code is transpiled, you may not need to worry too much about including an entire package just for a constants array since unused code may be dropped by the tree shaker. Hard to say more though without details. It might make sense for you to ask a new top level question.

Comment: @BennettDams No reason, your suggestion with `z.nativeEnum` looks like an improvement. I guess one reason to keep it is if you want a list of all methods for some reason, but if not then `nativeEnum` seems like less code and fewer type assertions.

Answer (score 10):

I have found out that using `z.custom<ExistingType>()` is working for me, and would be appropriate for this kind of problem.

[Edited]
According to @esteban-toress, we still have to add a validation function at the end like this `z.custom<ExistingType>((value) => //do something & return a boolean)`. Otherwise, just `z.custom<ExistingType>()` only returns `ZodAny` type which allows `any` value.

See docs:
https://zod.dev/?id=custom-schemas

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This works but worth noticing that you will need to add a validation function at the end otherwise zod will allow any value https://zod.dev/?id=custom-schemas

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the type directly you can use this:

```
const methods = ['get','GET',...] as const;

export type Method = (typeof methods)[number];

zod.enum(methods);
```

You get the best of both worlds this way; having the methods in a value you can use (array), and the type that you originally wanted.

Comment: That's cool but what I was going for is to use the Method type directly from axios, so that I don't have to repeat it, or at least I have typeScript verify that I use the correct type.

Comment: @Dotan I have a same thought. I though zod can reduce my time on calling request param type check, but now I fond out I have to do a repeated work, already done in typescript type defination, but in a zod way, to support runtime validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ts-to-zod](https://github.com/fabien0102/ts-to-zod) to export your `typescript` type into a `zod` schema.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34465774)